# Least quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$ is a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then, show that the least quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$ is a prime.  As a hint is given the fact that Legendre symbol is a homomorphism.

Comment: Not only is $\;1\;$ *not* a prime: it also *is not* a quadratic non-residue for any prime.

Comment: You should probably lookup the meaning of the word *consequently* :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** let $n$ be the least quadratic non residue $\mod p$, assume that $n=ab$ is not a prime then $a,b<n$ so $a$ and $b$ must be quadratic residus it follows that $\cdots\cdots$, contradiction,

---

As requested we can use the fact that the Legendre symbol is an homomorphism, in fact given a composite element $x=ab$ with $a,b< x$ then:
$$\left( \frac{a}{p} \right)\left( \frac{b}{p} \right)=\left( \frac{x}{p} \right) $$
and as consequence $x$ can not be the least quadratic non residue

Comment: It follows that since we firstly assumed that n is the least quadratic non-residue mod p then neither a nor b can be one so contradiction right ?? @Elaqqad

Comment: yes! this is it

Comment: It says here that the fact that the Legendre symbol  is a homomorphism is given as a hint. How do we use it? @Elaqqad

Comment: @DI... Exactly as hinted here and in the other answers: the product of QNR **is** a QR, and of course the product o QR is a QR .

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $\;a\;$ be the least quadratic non-residues (=QNR) for some prime $\;p\;$ . If $\;a=bc\;$ then it **must** be that *exactly* one of $\;b,\,c\;$ is a QNR, thus getting a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Lemma to the set $\,S\,$ of naturals that are quadratic residues mod $\,p.$

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\,\{1\}\subsetneq S\subsetneq \Bbb N$ is closed under multiplication then the least $\,n\not\in S\,$ is prime.

**Proof** $\ $ Else $\, n = ab,\,\ 1 < a,b < n\,$ so $\,a,b\in S\,\Rightarrow\, ab \in S,\,$ contradiction.